# Let $T: \mathbb{C}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^2$ be the linear operator defined by $T(z_1,z_2) = (z_1+5iz_2,(3+2i)z_1+3z_2)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: \mathbb{C}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^2$ be the linear operator defined by $T(z_1,z_2) = (z_1+5iz_2,(3+2i)z_1+3z_2)$.

I'm trying to find the matrix of $T$ relative to the standard basis (using the standard inner product) on $\mathbb{C}^2$ and then use this to determine the linear transformation $T^*$ (not just the matrix of $T^*$).

Thanks

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find the matrix, you have found $T^*$.  I will assume you are working over $\Bbb C$, so the dimension is $2$.  Then applying to the standard basis, $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$  we get the columns $(1,3+2i)^t$ and $(5i,3)^t$.  So the matrix is $\begin{pmatrix}1&5i\\3+2i&3\end{pmatrix}$.